# github repo not found after username change

Tags: github

I changed my github username recently. I created a new repo in my github and updated the remote origin using `git remote add origin` command. When I try to run `git push origin master`, however, I get `remote: Repository not found.` error.

I've looked through past SO questions on this topic and tried 1) successfully generating new SSH keys, 2) running the command with my `<username>:<pwd>@github.com`. I still see `remote: Repository not found.` error.

Any solutions?

Comment: Please add the contents of your local `.git/config` file.

Comment: I was able to figure this out: I removed the `[remote "origin"]` section of `.git/config`. Then, ran `git remote add origin` again and was able to push to master. Can anyone explain to me why this worked? Is this a workaround for a github bug??

Comment: Probably you added the second remote without removing the first one. Anyways it doesn't look like github bug. Likely just a some misunderstanding how git works from your side. Though I'm not sure.

Comment: @TagirValeev, this would've been a straight-forward reason, but it wasn't it. i made sure to delete the obsolete `remote origin` before executing `remote add` command. in any case, users shouldn't have to modify the config file if the obsolete remote reference was already removed.

Answer (score 0):

Part of the github URL for accessing your git repository is the username of the owner. For example:

https://github.com/koush/AndroidAsync.git

If the owner koush changes their name, this URL is no longer valid. The new URL needs to use the By removing the old URL with your obsolete username and adding the new URL with your updated username, you again have a valid URL.

In gitlab, there are warnings about what happens when you change the username:

> Changing your username will change path to all personal projects!

Comment: this is not the issue here. github states (https://help.github.com/articles/what-happens-when-i-change-my-username/) that repo references should be automatically updated upon username change: "When you change your username, GitHub automatically redirects references to your repositories. Web links to your existing repositories will continue to work."

Comment: It also says: "Technically, you'll also be able to continue pushing your local repositories to the old remote tracking URL without updating it. However, we recommend you update all existing remote repository URLs after changing your username. Because your old username is available for use by anyone else after you change it, that person would be able to create repositories that override the redirect entries."

Comment: Based on this info, I would guess that github's redirection is not working correctly.

Comment: You should also be able to verify by trying to clone the repository using the old URL.